# Powershell - Parse Output

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script that gathers a list (array) of all the groups a user is a member.  The values are presented using the DN.  How can I parse the output so I only get the group name (CN)?

DN = CN=Group Name,OU=Dept,OU=Company,DC=Domain,DC=Local

I only need the "Group Name" portion since this will be emailed to managers.

```
$user.memberof
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this:

```
$DN = 'CN=Group Name,OU=Dept,OU=Company,DC=Domain,DC=Local'
$CN = $DN -replace '^CN=(.+?),(?:OU|CN)=.+','$1'
$CN

Group Name
```

I've seen solutions that rely on splitting on the commas, but CNs can contain embedded commas (they have to be escaped with a backslash, but they can be in there).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Pathname COM object to parse distinguished name strings. It's awkward to use from PowerShell, so I wrote a module:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PowerShell-ADName

In your case, you could write this:

```
$dn = "CN=Group Name,OU=Dept,OU=Company,DC=domain,DC=local"
$nameOnly = Get-ADName -Format Leaf -ValuesOnly
# $nameOnly variable contains "Group Name"
```

The module is a wrapper for the Pathname object, which is really the best way for handing AD paths because it handles escaping properly.

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: @woldgrep Thanks for the notification. Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the value of the `distinguishedName` attribute by using a regular expression, that ensures that escaped commas are honored.

```
 ('CN=Group\,Name,OU=asdf' -split '(?<!\\),')[0];
 # Result:
 # CN=Group\,Name
```